# Approximate focus of spherical mirror. Where's the fault in my intuition?

Tags: calculus, geometry

This is Exercise 23 of the Chapter 3, Problem Plus section, of the 8th edition of Stewart Calculus.

> Suppose that we replace the parabolic mirror of Problem 22 by a spherical mirror. Although the mirror has no focus, we can show the existence of an approximate focus. In the figure, C is a semicircle with center O. A ray of light coming in toward the mirror parallel to the axis along the line PQ will be reflected to the point R on the axis so that ∠PQO = ∠OQR (the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection). What happens to the point R as P is taken closer and closer to the axis?

[image]

I've checked the solutions manual, and I know what the correct solution is and I also understand how the solutions manual arrives at it.

What I am not sure about is this:

Where the fault is in my initial intuition below?

> If $P$ is taken closer to the axis, then $Q \rightarrow A$, and thus $\theta \rightarrow 0$, and hence $R \rightarrow O$.

Comment: $\theta \to 0$ does not imply $R\to O$. $Q\to A$ and $QR=RO$, then $R\to F$ such that $AF=FO$. Angle $QOR=\theta$, $Q\to A$, $\theta \to 0$, then $R\to F$ such that angle $AOF=0$, that is $F$ is in segment AO.

Comment: Thanks you for the useful insight, @IvanKaznacheyeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle $OQR$ is isosceles, hence $QR=OR$. When $Q\to A$, then $R\to$ midpoint of $OA$.

When $\theta\to0$ then lines $QR$ and $QO$ both tend to line $AO$, but there is no reason to believe that point $R$ would tend to $O$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: @argonaut This example should show you that your intuition is wrong: $R$ needn't tend to $O$ as $\theta\to0$.

Comment: I understand - thank you